# Cannot remove Single Table Inheritance Doctrine entity in postFlush event subscriber

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a `postFlush` event subscriber/listener in a Symfony3 project that checks for existing items in the database from a collection, if it finds a match, it reassigns the existing entity to the `Document` and removes the new one using `orphanRemoval=true`. The code is working for `Tag` however when I try to do the same with an entity using inheritance mapping `Tool`, I get an error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
------------------------------------------------
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php at line 526
foreach ($joinColumns as $joinColumn) {
    $keys[] = $this->quoteStrategy->getJoinColumnName($joinColumn, $class, $this->platform);
}
```

I have a `Tool` and a `Part` which share a common table/structure `Equipment` as a `ManyToMany` relationship to a `Document`. They share a common structure and use SINGLE_TABLE inheritance with a `discr` field.

My `Document` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Document
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="documents", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_tags")
     *
     * @var Collection
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tool", inversedBy="documents", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="document_tools")
     *
     * @var Collection
     */
    private $tools;
}
```

My little `Tool` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Tool extends Equipment {}
```

`Equipment` abstract entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="equipment")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"tool" = "Tool", "part" = "Part"})
 */
abstract class Equipment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $partNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="KBS\Entity\Document\Document", mappedBy="equipment")
     *
     * @var Collection
     */
    private $documents;
}
```

Here's the listener code:

```
class DocumentListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $documents;

    /**
     * @param OnFlushEventArgs $event
     */
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $event)
    {
        $this->documents = [];
        $em = $event->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof Document) {
                $this->documents[] = $entity;
            }
        }

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof Document) {
                $this->documents[] = $entity;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param PostFlushEventArgs $event
     */
    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $event)
    {
        $em = $event->getEntityManager();
        if (!empty($this->documents)) {
            foreach ($this->documents as $document) {
                $this->removeTagDuplicates($em, $document);
                $this->removeToolDuplicates($em, $document);
            }

            $this->documents = [];
            $em->flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param Document $document
     */
    private function removeTagDuplicates(EntityManager $em, Document $document): void
    {
        $repository = $em->getRepository(Tag::class);
        foreach ($document->getTags() as $entity) {
            $numExisting = count($repository->findByLower($entity->getTitle()));

            /** @var Tag $firstMatch */
            $firstMatch = $repository->findOneByLower($entity->getTitle());
            if ($numExisting > 1 && $firstMatch->getChecksum() === $entity->getChecksum()) {
                $document->removeTag($entity);
                $document->addTag($firstMatch);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param Document $document
     */
    private function removeToolDuplicates(EntityManager $em, Document $document): void
    {
        $repository = $em->getRepository(Tool::class);
        foreach ($document->getTools() as $entity) {
            $numExisting = count($repository->findByLower($entity->getTitle()));

            /** @var Tool $firstMatch */
            $firstMatch = $repository->findOneByLower($entity->getTitle());
            if ($numExisting > 1 && $firstMatch->getChecksum() === $entity->getChecksum()) {
                $document->removeTool($entity);
                $document->addTool($firstMatch);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a reason why the mapping is being lost when we try to remove the orphaned `Tool`?

Comment: Entity Framework in PHP? Somehow I think not...

Comment: oops - removed. thanks.